# Typecasting and Generics

Tags: java, generics, return-value, nested-generics

I am working on a message parsing library where the message body comes back as a string in every case. I want to create a function that will automatically convert that result to the proper type, but I am not sure if its possible.

My structure is like this:
I have an enum called ReturnType. This contains this this contains the class variable of the return type.

I have a function map which maps the function that the user is trying to call with the return type of the message response.

I think I have it working to some point, but the problem is I have to include the class I want into the getTypedValue() method call, which I think is redundant since I already know the return type based on the ReturnType variable within the function map. Here is some code:

```
public enum ReturnType {
    NA(String.class),
    INTEGER(Integer.class),
    JSON(JsonElement.class),
    STRING(String.class),
    FLOAT(Float.class),
    DOUBLE(Double.class),
    IP_ADDRESS(InetAddress.class),
    UNKNOWN(String.class),
    BOOLEAN(Boolean.class);

    private Class<?> c;

    <T> ReturnType(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.c = clazz;
    }

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return this.c;
    }
}
```

Here is my getTypedValue() method:

```
public <T> T getTypedValue(String functionName, String value, Class<T> clazz) {
        ReturnType type = this.getReturnType(functionName);
        //TODO: Finish this
        if(type.getClazz().equals(clazz)) {
            switch(type) {
                case DOUBLE:
                    break;
                case FLOAT:
                    break;
                case INTEGER:
                    return clazz.cast(Integer.parseInt(value));
                case IP_ADDRESS:
                    break;
                case JSON:
                    break;
                case STRING:
                    return clazz.cast(value);
                case UNKNOWN:
                    return clazz.cast(value);
                default:
                    return clazz.cast(value);
            }
            return null;
        }else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(functionName +" does not support that class("+clazz.getSimpleName()+")");
        }
    }
```

Here is how a user would call get typed value. I put in a static value(15) for simplification but that will actually be the a method call that gets the result from the message response:

```
Integer volume = fm.getTypedValue("VOLUME", "15", Integer.class);
```

Is there any way to make it return the correct type without providing the class?   i.e.

```
Integer volume = fm.getTypedValue("VOLUME", "15");
Double minutes = fm.getTypedValue("MINUTES", "15.25");
Boolean isRunning = fm.getTypedValue("IS_RUNNING","true");
```

I'm unsure if its possible, and even if it is, the code I currently have I think might be a little ugly and difficult to follow.

Comment: Would it be an option to pass the value in the same type as the output? Then you could do `Integer volume = fm.getTypedValue("Volume", 15);`

Comment: Unfortunately no. The value is directly from the message response which is always a string. The goal of getTypedValue() is to get the value in the correct type. In the example you provided the output would be the same as the input, youre putting in integer 15 and getting back integer 15.

Comment: I understand. If you want to make it perfect, replace the `functionName` string with a function descriptor, which contains both a name and a generic type. Often, this approach is too expensive. But sometimes it's worth to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that, but you'll loose the advantage that the compiler gives you, of checking that the types are correct at compile time.

Using a `getTypedValue` implementation similar to:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public <T> T getTypedValue(String functionName, String value) {
    ReturnType type = this.getReturnType(functionName);
    switch(type) {
        case DOUBLE:
        case FLOAT:
        case JSON:
        case IP_ADDRESS:
            break;
        case INTEGER:
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(value);
        case STRING:
        case UNKNOWN:
        default:
            return (T) value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can use this without any problem:

```
int volume = fm.getTypedValue("VOLUME", "15");
```

But, by the other hand you can also use this (and the compiler won't show any error)

```
String volume = fm.getTypedValue("VOLUME", "15");
```

You instead will receive a runtime exception of type `ClassCastException` saying something like:

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

---

If you want something *probably* less error prone (that shows errors at compile time instead of runtime), you can define all the functions that you handle/know/provide in a class (the enum does not handle generics).

```
public final class Function<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    private Function(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public static final Function<Integer> VOLUME = new Function<>(Integer.class);
    public static final Function<Boolean> IS_RUNNING = new Function<>(Boolean.class);
    public static final Function<String> NAME = new Function<>(String.class);
}
```

(*You can refactor as you want, maybe adding `ReturnType`. You can add some custom logic in the `Function`. Also can pass the name of the function in the constructor parameters, in case you need the name later*)

Then change a little the `getTypedValue` method:

```
public <T> T getTypedValue(Function<T> function, String value) {
    ReturnType returnType = ReturnType.getReturnTypeByClass(function.getType());
    // ... same as before
}
```

You can create the method `getReturnTypeByClass()` to obtain the `returnType` depending on the received class.

And this will work:

```
int volume = test2.getTypedValue(Function.VOLUME, "123");
```

And this will show a compile time error, very easy to detect and fix:

```
String volume = test2.getTypedValue(Function.VOLUME, "123");
```

Finally, you can separate the definition of the `Function` class and the declarations of the functions in another class names for example `Functions`.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! This is perfect! Im going to try and adapt it into my Function Map class that I have already. Excellent approach! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no way. The compiler expects that the type is lost during runtime which would make it unsafe to assign it to anything other than `Object`

Alternatively you can return an `Object` and make multiple `instanceof` checks, but I think that's just worse.

Another alternative is to call the method with the generic provided. Unfortunately, I'm unsure if this will result in other compile errors or not. Try something like

```
Double minutes = fm.<Double>getTypedValue("MINUTES", "15.25");
```

There is nothing wrong with providing a `Class` instance to a generic method, I've seen it like that in many different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your enum as below.

```
public enum ReturnType {
    NA(String.class) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String param) {
            return param;
        }
    },
    INTEGER(Integer.class) {
        @Override
        public Integer getValue(String param) {
            return Integer.valueOf(param);
        }
    },
    JSON(JsonElement.class) {
        @Override
        public <T> T getValue(String param) {
            return null;
        }
    },
    STRING(String.class) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String param) {
            return param;
        }
    },
    FLOAT(Float.class),
    DOUBLE(Double.class),
    IP_ADDRESS(InetAddress.class),
    UNKNOWN(String.class),
    BOOLEAN(Boolean.class);

    private Class<?> c;

    <T> ReturnType(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.c = clazz;
    }

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return this.c;
    }

    public abstract <T>  T getValue(String param);
}
```

You have to implement in every ReturnType to return generated T value from String.

Then you can use ReturnType enum as below.

```
public <T> T getTypedValue(String functionName, String value, Class<T> clazz) {
        ReturnType type = this.getReturnType(functionName);
        if(type.getClazz().equals(clazz)) {
           return type.getValue(value);
        }
        return null;
}
```

Please be kind enough to ignore compiler errors and please fix it. I want to give you an idea to implement other way.